# I want to disable all types of rules in specefic product in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is  wallet
  [image]

Comment: is this catalog price rules or sales price rules?

Comment: cart price rules(sales)